# Sass - File to import not found or unreadable - yeoman webapp generator

Tags: sass, generator, bower, yeoman

I have annoying issue with sass plugin. I use yeoman webapp geneator with default configuration. When I want to build production files (gulp command) I get sass error "File to import not found or unreadable [...]". It works only at first running gulp command – dist folder build properly. But when I want to run gulp command again I keep receiving this error (I have to restart computer to make it works again – at first run :) ). On the other hand, running "gulp serve" (live preview) command gets this same error only at fresh start – when I modify some .scss, files compile properly.

This is the main SCSS file:

```
// bower:scss
@import "bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.scss";
// endbower
@import '_reset', '_fontello', '_variables', '_helpers', '_basic', 
'_widerScreens', '_carousel';
```

Yeoman webapp generator v.3.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution. Try to reproduce.

https://garystanton.co.uk/gulp-sass-file-to-import-not-found-or-unreadable/